# MS Bot ThumbnailCard is throwing error on Facebook Messenger

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, facebook-messenger

When I am passing a ThumbnailCard object to TurnContext for Facebook Messanger Channel. It throws an error as follows

`Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'`

Exception Stacktrace -

```
    at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.<ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.<ReplyToActivityAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.<SendActivitiesAsync>d__33.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<<SendActivitiesAsync>g__SendActivitiesThroughAdapter|1>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.<SendActivityAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()**at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.<ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.<ReplyToActivityAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.<SendActivitiesAsync>d__33.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<<SendActivitiesAsync>g__SendActivitiesThroughAdapter|1>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.<SendActivityAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()**
```

while working fine for MsTeams, Skype and custom web chat interface.

I am passing following object

```
    ThumbnailCard card = new ThumbnailCard()
                {
                    Tap = new CardAction()
                    {
                        Value = "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXX.core.windows.net/usecase-files/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.pdf",
                        Type = "openUrl"
                    },
                    Buttons = new List<CardAction>
                    {
                            new CardAction { Type = "openUrl", Value = "http://www.devenvexe.com" }
                        },
                    Images = new List<CardImage> { new CardImage(url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541963463532-d68292c34b19?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8Ym9va3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80") },
                };
```

Its working fine when I remove the buttons from above object. Please help me out.

Comment: strange issue, try with https url in card action value.

Comment: @RajeeshMenoth: Thanks for your help but its not working. Issue is with Buttons property. I have tried with blank Value CardActikon but issue is same.

Comment: Add all the property inside the card action instead of giving two. E.g new CardAction {Title = "Cup 1",
DisplayText = "You chose Cup1",Value = "cup1",ChannelData = new { id = 1, status = "wise" }}

Comment: @RajeeshMenoth: Thanks for your help but not working.